# Merge countries using Cartopy

Tags: matplotlib, geopandas, cartopy

I am using the following code to make a map for Sweden, Norway and Finland together as one area. however, I am struggling with it. I'm following this example, Python Mapping in Matplotlib Cartopy Color One Country.

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from cartopy.io import shapereader
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import geopandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def rect_from_bound(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax):
    """Returns list of (x,y)'s for a rectangle"""
    xs = [xmax, xmin, xmin, xmax, xmax]
    ys = [ymax, ymax, ymin, ymin, ymax]
    return [(x, y) for x, y in zip(xs, ys)]

# request data for use by geopandas
resolution          = '10m'
category            = 'cultural'
name                = 'admin_0_countries'
countries           = ['Norway', 'Sweden', 'Finland']
shpfilename         = shapereader.natural_earth(resolution, category, name)
df                  = geopandas.read_file(shpfilename)
extent              = [2, 32, 55, 72]
# get geometry of a country
for country in (countries):
    poly = [df.loc[df['ADMIN'] == country]['geometry'].values[0]]
    stamen_terrain              = cimgt.StamenTerrain()
    # projections that involved
    st_proj = stamen_terrain.crs  #projection used by Stamen images
    ll_proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()  #CRS for raw long/lat
    # create fig and axes using intended projection
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,9))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(122, projection=st_proj)
    ax.add_geometries(poly, crs=ll_proj, facecolor='none', edgecolor='black')
    pad1 = 0.5  #padding, degrees unit
    exts = [poly[0].bounds[0] - pad1, poly[0].bounds[2] + pad1, poly[0].bounds[1] - pad1, poly[0].bounds[3] + pad1];
    ax.set_extent(exts, crs=ll_proj)
    # make a mask polygon by polygon's difference operation
    # base polygon is a rectangle, another polygon is simplified switzerland
    msk = Polygon(rect_from_bound(*exts)).difference( poly[0].simplify(0.01) )
    msk_stm  = st_proj.project_geometry (msk, ll_proj)  # project geometry to the projection used by stamen
    # get and plot Stamen images
    ax.add_image(stamen_terrain, 8) # this requests image, and plot
    # plot the mask using semi-transparency (alpha=0.65) on the masked-out portion
    ax.add_geometries( msk_stm, st_proj, zorder=12, facecolor='white', edgecolor='none', alpha=0.65)
    ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
    plt.show()
```

What I have is separated maps. THoguh I need only one map of them.
[image]
Can you please help?
Thank you.

Comment: FYI. For a new user, you can't vote up my answer until you gain some reputation points. But you can mark it “accepted”, and earn "+2" reputation. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62448828/python-cartopy-map-clip-area-outside-country-polygon/62502422#62502422) that you adapted to your work is good for a single country. If multiple contiguous countries are new target, one need to select all of them and dissolve into a single geometry. Only a few lines of code need to be modified.

Example: new target countries: ['Norway','Sweden', 'Finland']

The line of code that need to be replaced:

```
poly = [df.loc[df['ADMIN'] == 'Switzerland']['geometry'].values[0]]
```

Replace it with these lines of code:

```
scan3 = df[ df['ADMIN'].isin(['Norway','Sweden', 'Finland']) ]
scan3_dissolved = scan3.dissolve(by='LEVEL')
poly = [scan3_dissolved['geometry'].values[0]]
```

And you should get a plot similar to this:

[image: scan3]

Comment: Perfect!! this is what I want to do... Thank you!

Comment: @YOUSEFALBUHAISI The proper way to thank is clicking `accept the answer`. ;)

Comment: I have another question, How could I mask an .nc file using the above mask?