# Improve resolution of Cartopy map

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

The following code generates a map of the US with a contour line for every state. The problem is that the image looks like it was generated with 1990s technology. How can I significantly improve the quality of the figure, i.e. increase the resolution of the background?

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 400

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], projection=ccrs.LambertConformal())
ax.set_extent([-125, -66.5, 20, 50], ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.stock_img()


shapename = 'admin_1_states_provinces_lakes_shp'
states_shp = shpreader.natural_earth(resolution='110m', category='cultural',
                                     name=shapename)

ax.outline_patch.set_visible(False)  # don't draw the map border
ax.set_title('My map of the lower 48')

# example state coloring
colors = {
    'Minnesota': [0, 1, 0],
    'Texas': "#FF0000",
    'Montana': "blue",
}
default_color = [0.9375, 0.9375, 0.859375]

for state in shpreader.Reader(states_shp).records():
    facecolor = colors.get(state.attributes['name'], default_color)
    ax.add_geometries([state.geometry], ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                      facecolor=facecolor, edgecolor='black', alpha=0.5,linewidth=0.1)

# example data
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['city', 'lat', 'lon'], data=[
    ('Hoboken', 40.745255, -74.034775),
    ('Port Hueneme', 34.155834, -119.202789),
    ('Auburn', 42.933334, -76.566666),
    ('Jamestown', 42.095554, -79.238609),
    ('Fulton', 38.846668, -91.948059),
    ('Bedford', 41.392502, -81.534447)
])

ax.plot(df['lon'], df['lat'], transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
        ms=8, ls='', marker='*')
#plt.show()
plt.savefig("usa.png")
plt.close()
```

[image]

Comment: If you mean the crude image of `ax.stock_img()`, you can get finer images from the internet. For example NASA Blue Marble for base map.

Comment: @swatchai Do you know whether there exists repository for base maps? Is there some documentation on the usage of base maps, including a description of which images qualify as 'base maps'? I didn't know about the existence of 'base maps' until I read your comment and was able to search for "cartopy basemap blue marble" and found some example code. Cartopy could benefit from some more examples. Below I posted what I found. Thanks!

Comment: It is more appropriate to use web maps' tiles. Here is one example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64925988/merge-countries-using-cartopy .

Comment: Hi, I found a 'base maps' gallery of NASA https://visibleearth.nasa.gov/collection/1484/blue-marble 
@JorisKinable,

Answer (score 5):

The low quality image is caused by the stock image (`ax.stock_img()`) which for reasons unknown to me of very poor quality. I found the following solutions:

(1) Don't use any background, but add a number of features:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.COASTLINE,linewidth=0.3)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS, linestyle=':',linewidth=0.3)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAKES, alpha=0.5)
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.RIVERS)
ax.set_extent([-125, -66.5, 20, 50])
```

Another example for this solution can be found [here](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.15/examples/features.html)

[image: Simple map using features]

(2) Use a custom background image.
This solution requires downloading a basemap background image such as [Blue Marble](https://neo.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/view.php?datasetId=BlueMarbleNG-TB) or [ETOPO Global Relief](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/global.html).
As per these [instructions](http://earthpy.org/tag/cartopy.html), once downloaded, you must set a global environment variable: `CARTOPY_USER_BACKGROUNDS=path_to_map_folder` which points to the folder where you stored the downloaded maps. In addition, you must create a JSON file called `images.json` and store it in the same folder. Example contents of the JSON file:

```
{"__comment__": "JSON file specifying the image to use for a given type/name and resolution. Read in by cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.read_user_background_images.",
  "BM": {
    "__comment__": "Blue Marble Next Generation, July ",
    "__source__": "https://neo.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/view.php?datasetId=BlueMarbleNG-TB",
    "__projection__": "PlateCarree",
    "low": "bluemarble1degrees.jpeg",
    "high": "bluemarble01degrees.jpeg"},
  "ETOPO": {
    "__comment__": "ETOPO",
    "__source__": "https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/global.html",
    "__projection__": "PlateCarree",
    "high": "color_etopo1_ice_low.jpg"}
}
```

Finally, one can use the following code to add the desired background:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent([-125, -66.5, 20, 50], ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.background_img(name='ETOPO', resolution='high')
```

The above code would use the ETOPO background. To use the Blue Marble background, change the last line to: `ax.background_img(name='BM', resolution='high')`. Note that the name and resolution parameters must match the entries in the JSON file.

ETOPO:
[image: Etopo map]
BLue Marble:
[image: Blue marble map]

Finally, as per this [Kaggle post](https://www.kaggle.com/carlmcbrideellis/bluemarble-and-etopo-in-cartopy), it must also be possible to load the basemap as a image background directly. This would be more convenient as it bypasses the step of setting an Environment variable and writing a JSON file:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent([-125, -66.5, 20, 50], ccrs.Geodetic())
img = plt.imread('./bluemarble01degrees.jpeg')
img_extent = (-125, -66.5, 20, 50)
ax.imshow(img, origin='upper', extent=img_extent, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

Unfortunately I did not get the above solution to work, as it does not zoom in on the relevant section of the map:

[image]

Comment: Please try with `projection=ccrs.LambertConformal()`.

Comment: I followed the 2nd point and it works but when defining the global varibale you have to write it in this way: `os.environ["CARTOPY_USER_BACKGROUNDS"] = dir_path`

Comment: Blue marble link is dead.